# How to compare two tables and select not exist records from first table in SQL

Tags: sql, join

```
select ID,MRN,FileName from Upload$ t1
EXCEPT
Select MRN,FileName from Sheet1$
```

Here i would like to compare MRN and FileName from both table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `EXCEPT` statement is correct as you need to check records which are not exists in second table from first table.

```
select t1.* from Upload$ t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sheet1$ S 
       ON S.MRN = t1.MRN AND t1.FileName = S.FileName 
WHERE S.MRN IS NULL AND S.FileName IS NULL
```

So, here is alternative approach via `JOIN`s (i.e. `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) to check record which are not exists in second table from first table and return not exists records from first table

Comment: Just to simplify, just with one comparison in where should be enough, you don’t have to check both attributes. If one of them was null, it wouldn’t join neither with the table